# Changing the value in a drop down list Excel C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

so I have asked how to change the value in a cell inside of excel using c#, but what if I want to change the value of a drop down list. The code I am using for sheet modifying is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
 public virtual Object ActiveSheet { get; set; }

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 var sheet = (Excel._Worksheet)this.ActiveSheet; 
 sheet.Cells[6, 6] = "6";
 }
```

I get the sheet to open but when it goes to the list it gives me NullReferenceException.

Comment: its a drop down list for example one of the drop down lists has 2, 4, 6 as options and I have it to access the sheet and now i want to automatically be able to change the list value

Comment: What **kind** of drop-down list ?  There are 3 different types I can think of.

Comment: data validation list which is not part of the developer tools its built in to excel.

Comment: As long as it's a valid value can't you just set the cell value?

Comment: yeah I guess that would work I didnt even think of that. Just get rid of the drop downs completely and just input the values!!! Thanks I am going to try that now

Comment: hmm came up with NullReferenceException somethings still wrong.

Comment: Show more code, and indicate which line gives the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out took me a long time please use it!!

```
  using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

  public virtual Object ActiveSheet { get; set; }

  private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Gets ActiveSheet to Modify
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;

        //Start Excel and get Application object.
        oXL = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); 
        oXL.Visible = true;
        oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook; 
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

        //Generate Linear Guide Supports using Design Table in Solidworks
        if (comboBox1.Text == "0")//no external rails
        {
            oSheet.Cells[6, 4] = "0"; //Change Value in Cell in Excel Cell Location [y-axis, x-axis]
        }
        //Quit Excel
        oXL.Quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to navigate through the drop down list.If you are using drop down object.
We are using shapes.item

You need to identify the shape object name from your excel.

```
var control = xlWorksheet.Shapes.Item("Drop Down 22").ControlFormat;
control.ListIndex = 5; \\This allows you to change the drop down to 5th element
```

In case you are trying to change a combo box which is based on the cell of a excel sheet , you can directly change the cell value

```
 Excel.Range xlRangeloc= xlWorksheetH.get_Range("D5");

                            xlRangeloc.Value = "OptionOne";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;
//create exel
oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\\Desktop\Test.xlsx");
oXL.Visible = true;//Can make it false when don't want to see the excel file
//give u name of workbook
 string ExcelWorkbookname = oWB.Name;
// statement get the worksheet count  
 int worksheetcount = oWB.Worksheets.Count;
string path = oWB.Path;

oSheet = (_Worksheet)oWB.Sheets.get_Item(1);
string str = oSheet.Name;
//IMP: on Excel right click on drop down u can see the drop down name on left top most corner which u r providing below.
// It can be anything like Drop Down 5,Drop Down 6,Drop Down 7 etc
  var dropdownValue= oSheet.Shapes.Item("Drop Down 5").ControlFormat; 
dropdownValue.ListIndex = 2; //This allows you to change the drop down to 2nd element
```

//this code works but Interop is very very slow.Instead use Oledb