# C# Excel select value from drop-down list

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have an Excel document with a **drop-down list** and I am trying to get the values of the list and **select** one (or at least be able to select one by the index since they won't change).

I tried setting the value with **SetCellValue** on both **ICell** and **XSSFCell** but it doesn't work correctly, it just inputs the value and I need it to be selected since other parts of the Excel document change accordingly.

Is there a way to do this using NPOI or any other C# Excel libraries?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7446478/1132334

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read excel list elements (data validation) using C# Excel Interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606170/how-to-read-excel-list-elements-data-validation-using-c-sharp-excel-interop)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using NPOI. You may try one of these approaches. You can also setCellFormula, SetAsActiveCell , setErrorValue, setCellType etc. using same approach.

```
//Approach 1
 var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
 row.Cells[targetColumn].SetCellValue("whatertypevalue");

 //Approach 2 
 var namedRow = wb.GetSheetAt(sheetIndex).CreateRow(rowindex);
 namedRow.CreateCell(columnIndex).SetCellValue("whatertypevalue");

//Approach 3 
var namedRow1 = wb.GetSheetAt(0).GetRow(rowindex);
namedRow1.Cells[targetColumn].SetCellValue("whatertypevalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to navigate through the drop down list.If you are using drop down object. We are using shapes.item

You need to identify the shape object name from your excel.

```
var control = xlWorksheet.Shapes.Item("Drop Down 22").ControlFormat;
control.ListIndex = 5; \\This allows you to change the drop down to 5th element


 Excel.Range xlRangeloc= xlWorksheetH.get_Range("D5");
 xlRangeloc.Value = "OptionOne";\\If the drop down is a combo box bound to a excel cell value
```