# How do I select an item in an Excel drop down in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a little program (C#, using Visual Studio 2015) that populates an Excel file.
This Excel sheet contains a drop down list, which is populated with data from a different worksheet in the same file.

Currently you have to select the desired item by hand, so it can set a number of variables. The sheet has a macro with some calculations that need these variables. 
The program I'm making is going to automate the process, so I need to select the right item in the list programatically and run the macro afterwards. This is where I'm stuck. I can add values to other cells and the macro runs fine, but it's using the default list value.

I've been looking for a solution, but can't get it to work.
This does nothing for me:
[Changing the value in a drop down list Excel C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446478/changing-the-value-in-a-drop-down-list-excel-c-sharp)

```
worksheet.Cells[4, 3] = "5";
```

where "5" is an arbitrary index just to get it to change. Doesn't work.
Replacing "5" by "actual string value" doesn't work either.

I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application object to control the file.

How do I select an item from the list? Either by matching string or by index, both will do.

Comment: Have you tried `worksheet.Cells[4, 3].Value2 = "The Value"`?

Comment: Yep, didn't work either.
I tried adding sleep right after opening the file and another before running the macro, maybe the list wasn't populated yet. Doesn't solve it though..

Comment: Some more info:
The cell value does get updated, but upon opening the file it resets to the default list item. The new value is visible for a very short time.

Comment: Refer this answer on changing the drop down value
<https://stackoverflow.com/a/56024648/7892990>

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!
The problem was that the cell value got overridden by a value in another worksheet.. Changing this one in stead of the actual drop down list did the trick.